# Sorl-thumbnail bad url's

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I setup sorl-thumbnail according to instructions, but none of the images are appearing when I try to use the templatetags in my app.

It appears that the url's are not valid, but it's not clear what additional configuration is needed.

A image like like this is generated:

```
<img src="cache/e5/25/e5253a328b9130ecd7d820893f44b0e6.jpg" width="100" height="100">
```

How does "cache/..." get resolved to a request for an image?  These requests are relative to my application, not to sorl-thumbnail:

```
[31/May/2011 07:13:05] "GET /myapp/cache/e5/25/cache/e5/25/cache/00/73/0073095ee4b968b45386ef3fec4f389c.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 1004
```

Here are the relevant lines in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the  admin:                                          
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'mysite.myapp',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
)

CACHES = {
#    'default': {                                                                           
#        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',                          
#        'LOCATION': 'cache',                                                               
#    }                                                                                    
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a                     
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).                    
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com", "http://example.com/media/"                        
MEDIA_URL = ''

# URL prefix for admin media -- CSS, JavaScript and images. Make sure to use   a              
# trailing slash.                                                                           
# Examples: "http://foo.com/media/", "/media/".                                             
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'
```

This is the code in my template:

```
{% thumbnail auction.item.image "100x100" crop="center" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

The image is definitely getting uploaded (I checked the directory specified in upload_to), and when I was using the filesystem cache they were getting stored in the directory cache/ relative to my app.  I changed it to use memcache to see if that would help.

Comment: Is your MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT set up correctly? Can you view the normal images (i.e. non-thumbnails)?

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL are not setup yet.  I don't have any static images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to configure MEDIA_URL correctly. The ["url" attribute](http://thumbnail.sorl.net/reference/image.html#url) of an ImageFile is basically just a pass-through from the underlying storage backend. For out-of-the-box Django, the [upload_to path is appended to MEDIA_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) to generate the URL for a FileField.

What you have: '' + 'cache/e5/25/e5253a328b9130ecd7d820893f44b0e6.jpg'
What you want: '/media/' + 'cache/e5/25/e5253a328b9130ecd7d820893f44b0e6.jpg'

Note: you would need to make sure that MEDIA_URL is aliased/mapped to whatever directory Django is uploading your files to (MEDIA_ROOT).

----- EDIT ----
See the following links to the source of the default Django storage backend.
https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.3/django/core/files/storage.py#L154
https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.3/django/core/files/storage.py#L240

Comment: Doesn't sorl-thumbnail access the images from a cache?  I currently have it configured to use memcache.  If I configure the MEDIA_URL to just serve the files directly from MEDIA_URL/cache... then it's not going to get them from memcache.

Comment: According to the sorl-thumbnail docs I linked above, the ImageFile.url attribute is calculated using the storage backend.  The Django default storage backend uses MEDIA_URL. Thus, if you're using that backend then you need to set MEDIA_URL.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.  I added the 'media/' to my url's, too.

Comment: You should probably use the 'django.core.context_processors.media' template context processor and use {{ MEDIA_URL }} in your template instead of hardcoding.

Comment: he's not hardcoding anything, that img tag with the cache url is generated by Sorl Thumbnail based on... yes, the MEDIA_URL