# sorl-thumbnail not linking properly

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I installed sorl-thumbnail and a lot seems to go right. For every {% thumbnail %} tag some folders and a thumbnail image are created in a "cache" folder.

Inside the template the image url is rendered as something like "cache/7b/74/7b74e7338fd08c52e3ac7526aa5eb7b6.jpg", which seems correct as well. However no image is displayed. When I try following the cache link, it results in a 404 error.

Comment: On the rendered page, does the link starts like `cache/7b/74...` or is it `/media/cache/7b/74` ?... if it's like the first one, then c&p the link and prepend '/media/' to it. If the image shows, then, the problem is the generated url. Can you post the part where you're generating the thumbnail?

Comment: Also, if your problem is the missing `/media/`, take a look at this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187465/sorl-thumbnail-bad-urls

Comment: @andzep Yes, I did not have the /media/ links set up, so I fixed it now. It works ok, thx. Can you resubmit your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the rendered page, does the link starts like `cache/7b/74...` or is it `/media/cache/7b/74` ?... if it's like the first one, then c&p the link and prepend `/media/` to it. If the image shows, then the problem is the generated url.

Also, if your problem is the missing `/media/`, take a look at this other question: [Sorl-thumbnail bad url's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187465/sorl-thumbnail-bad-urls)